# Facebook: How to configure the sentences of a custom story?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Facebook's Open Graph Stories configuration contains a "One to Two" sentence with the following structure:

```
[user] did [object1.title and object2.title] in [AppName]
```

Here `[object1.title and object2.title]` is actually just one placeholder.
Now I'd like to replace it with the following structure:

```
[user] did [object1.customfield and object2.customfield] in [AppName]
```

What syntax must be used-/what must be entered to create the `[object1.customfield and object2.customfield]` placeholder?

Through an other post here on SO, I've figured out that a single placeholder can be created using the syntax `{object.customfield}`, with which the following sentence structure could be created:

```
[user] did [object.customfield] and [object.customfield] in [AppName]
```

But here, the same object is referenced twice here. Is there a way to use the `{object.customfield}` syntax to get a result of `{object1.customfield}`?
Directly entering `{object1.customfield}` does not get replaced with the corresponding placeholder, so I wonder what the right syntax might look like.
Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A simple answer is no, this function is still not supported by facebook.

Comment: @folizc, thanks for the clarification. Does an open graph story get approved if the "One to Two" sentence is grammatically incorrect? How about if the sentence is changed to "[user] did SomethingHardCodedBecauseOfFacebooksLackOfFunctionality in [AppName]" - would that be approved?